# Spatial Points function gives error message

Tags: r

Please let me know why the last line in this code gives the following error and how I can fix it? I am running R version 4.3.1.

```
library(sp)
library(adehabitatHR)

# read in a .csv which contains lat and long for my data points

mydata <- read.csv("D:/Bats/mydata.csv")

# create spatial points object

datapoints <- SpatialPoints(cbind(mydata$lon, mydata$lat))
```

> datapoints<-SpatialPoints(cbind(mydata$lon,mydata$lat))
> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :
> unable to find an inherited method for function ‘coordinates’ for signature ‘"NULL"’

I tried various ways to right this code differently but being a novice to R, I am lost at this point.

Comment: You almost certainly have a problem with your input data frame, which you haven’t shown us. Inspect `mydata`. If the problem isn’t obvious, post the output from `dput(mydata)` - or `dput(head(mydata))` in your question.

Comment: You might want to use `mydata <- read.csv("D:/Bats/mydata.csv", header = TRUE)` as this will indicate that the first line of the .csv actually contains the column names and then `mydata$lon` will be meaningful. Welcome to Stackoverflow.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try both your recommendations and let you know. Such a great community site to help all of us learn and improve. - Prabha

Comment: Output for dput(mydata) : > mydata<-read.csv("D:/Bats/mydata.csv")
> dput(mydata)
structure(list(OID_ = 1:146, Grupo = 1:146, Murcielago = c(3L, 
3L, 3L), Angulo_eq = c(139L, 155L), Lat = c(-83.53, -83.53, 
-83.529722, -83.529722, -83.528889, -83.529722, -83.53, -83.529722), Lon = c(10.5966666666667, 10.5966666666667, 
10.5966666666667, 10.5966666666667, 10.5938888888889,)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -146L))
 I shortened the output since it is too many chars to paste here in the comments

Comment: Output for dput(head(mydata)): > mydata<-read.csv("D:/Bats/mydata.csv")
> dput(head(mydata))
structure(list(OID_ = 1:6, Grupo = 1:6, Murcielago = c(3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), Angulo_eq = c(139L, 155L, 263L, 225L, 255L, 
243L), Lat = c(-83.53, -83.53, -83.529722, -83.529722, -83.528889, 
-83.529722), Lon = c(10.5966666666667, 10.5966666666667, 10.5966666666667, 
10.5966666666667, 10.5938888888889, 10.5944444444444)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: Unreal! I found what my problem was- the names "lat" and "lon" as in script was "Lat" and "Lon" in the .csv. So changed it to lowercase. Just wish the error mesg wasn't so cryptic. Thank you for your suggestions, helped me find the issue for sure. - Prabha